¿Cómo mostrar cada registro que tengo en mi BD por separado, en una tabla de HTML usando JavaScript y PHP?
Mostrar por separado todos los registros que tengo en mi BD relacionados a un dato, en un tabla HTML usando JavaScript y PHP.
¡Hola, a tod@s!
Estoy tratando de encontrar la instrucción para separar y mostrar en una tabla HTML, cada registro que se relaciona con otro registro que tengo en mi BD. Estoy trabajándolo con JavaScript y PHP, ¿alguien puede ayudarme y guiarme para trabajarlo y llegar al resultado?.

Las herramientas que estoy usando para el ejemplo, es servidor local XAMPP, HTML, PHP, MySQL y JavaScript.


Base de Datos (base.sql)
- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.2.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: 127.0.0.1
-- Tiempo de generación: 17-10-2024 a las 18:52:12
-- Versión del servidor: 10.4.32-MariaDB
-- Versión de PHP: 8.1.25

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `proyecto`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `base`
--

CREATE TABLE `base` (
  `ID` int(250) NOT NULL,
  `CLAVE` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `DESCRIPCION` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `UM` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `LOTE` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `CADUCIDAD` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `EXISTENCIA` varchar(250) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `base`
--

INSERT INTO `base` (`ID`, `CLAVE`, `DESCRIPCION`, `UM`, `LOTE`, `CADUCIDAD`, `EXISTENCIA`) VALUES
(1, '22', 'Caseinato de calcio en Polvo. Cada 100 g contienen: Proteínas 86.0 g a 90.0 g. Grasas 0.0 a 2.0 g. Minerales 3.8 a 6.0 g. Humedad 0.0 a 6.2 g.', 'Envase con 100 g.', '403402041B', '31-ago-25', '4030'),
(2, '22', 'Caseinato de calcio en Polvo. Cada 100 g contienen: Proteínas 86.0 g a 90.0 g. Grasas 0.0 a 2.0 g. Minerales 3.8 a 6.0 g. Humedad 0.0 a 6.2 g.', 'Envase con 100 g.', 'A304003', '30-abr-25', '1792'),
(3, '22', 'Caseinato de calcio en Polvo. Cada 100 g contienen: Proteínas 86.0 g a 90.0 g. Grasas 0.0 a 2.0 g. Minerales 3.8 a 6.0 g. Humedad 0.0 a 6.2 g.', 'Envase con 100 g.', 'E404019', '31-ene-26', '1792'),
(4, '1956', 'Amikacina. Solución inyectable, cada ampolleta o frasco contiene: Sulfato de amikacina equivalente a 500 mg de amikacina.', 'Envase con 1 ampolleta o frasco con 2ml.', 'R23J03', '30-jun-25', '5516'),
(5, '1956', 'Amikacina. Solución inyectable, cada ampolleta o frasco contiene: Sulfato de amikacina equivalente a 500 mg de amikacina.', 'Envase con 1 ampolleta o frasco con 2ml.', 'R23U49', '31-jul-25', '4801');

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `base`
--
ALTER TABLE `base`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `base`
--
ALTER TABLE `base`
  MODIFY `ID` int(250) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;


CONEXION A MI BD (dbcontroller.php)
<?php
class DBController {
  private $host = "localhost";
  private $user = "root";
  private $password = "";
  private $database = "*";
  private $conexion;
  
  function __construct() {
    $this->conexion = $this->connectDB();
  }
  
  function connectDB() {
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
    return $conexion;
  }
  
  function runQuery($query) {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conexion,$query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $resultset[] = $row;
    }
    if(!empty($resultset))
      return $resultset;
  }
  
  function insertQuery($query) {
      mysqli_query($this->conexion, $query);
      $insert_id = mysqli_insert_id($this->conexion);
      return $insert_id;
  }
  
  function getIds($query) {
      $result = mysqli_query($this->conexion,$query);
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          $resultset[] = $row[0];
      }
      if(!empty($resultset))
          return $resultset;
  }
  
   function numRows($query) {
        $result  = mysqli_query($this->conexion, $query);
        $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        return $rowcount;
    }
}
?>


Selección de datos a mi BD (dato1.php)
 <?php
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    # conectare la base de datos
 include('dbcontroller.php');
$db_handle = new DBController();

$return_arr = array();
$array=[];

$sqlc = "SELECT * FROM base WHERE  CLAVE like '%".$_GET['term']."%'";

$faq = $db_handle->runQuery($sqlc);


foreach($faq as $k=>$v) {
/* Recuperar y almacenar en conjunto los resultados de la consulta.*/       
    $row_array['value']= $faq[$k]['CLAVE'];
    $row_array['CLAVE']=$faq[$k]['CLAVE'];
    
    $row_array['DESCRIPCION']=$faq[$k]['DESCRIPCION'];
    $row_array['UM']=$faq[$k]['UM'];
    $row_array['ID']=$faq[$k]['ID'];
    //$row_array['CLAVE']=$faq[$k]['CLAVE'];
    $row_array['LOTE'][]=$faq[$k]['LOTE'];
    $row_array['CADUCIDAD'][]=$faq[$k]['CADUCIDAD'];
    $row_array['EXISTENCIA'][]=$faq[$k]['EXISTENCIA'];
    
    
    $return_arr[""] = $row_array;
}
/* Codifica el resultado del array en JSON. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
?>


Intefaz (salidax3.php)
<?php
$conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', '*');
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>GUI</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prueba.css">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.0.4.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

  <!--SCRIPT-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#CLAVE").autocomplete({
        source: "dato1.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('#clave1').val(ui.item.clave1);
          $('#DESCRIPCION').val(ui.item.DESCRIPCION);
          $('#UM').val(ui.item.UM);
          $('#ID2').val(ui.item.ID2);
          $('#CLAVE2').val(ui.item.CLAVE2);
          $('#LOTE').val(ui.item.LOTE);
          $('#CADUCIDAD').val(ui.item.CADUCIDAD);
          $('#EXISTENCIA').val(ui.item.EXISTENCIA);


          $("#CLAVE").focus();
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
  
  <!-------------->
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(buscar_datos());
    function buscar_datos(consulta){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'dato1.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {consulta: consulta},
      })
      .done(function(respuesta){
        $("#datos").html(respuesta);
      })
      .fail(function(){
        console.log("error");
        
      })
    } 
  </script>
</head> 

<body>
  <h1 align="center"></h1>
  <div class="container">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">   
      <div class="card-group mt-3">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="card text-center border-info">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">-</h4>
              </div>
            </div>   
          </div>

          <div class="col-9">
            <div class="card text-center border-info">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
                <br>
                <form action="" method="POST" class="row g-3">
                 <!------->
                 <div class="row mb-3">
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label for="inputCity" class="form-label">CLAVE</label>
                    <input type="text" name="CLAVE"class="form-control" id="CLAVE">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <label for="inputState" class="form-label">DESCRIPCION</label>
                    <input type="text" name="DESCRIPCION" class="form-control" id="DESCRIPCION">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label for="inputZip" class="form-label">U.M.</label>
                    <input type="text" name="UM" class="form-control" id="UM">
                  </div>
                  <hr>
                  <!--TABLA-->
                  <div class="container">
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col">LOTE</th>
                          <th scope="col">CADUCIDAD</th>
                          <th scope="col">EXISTENCIA</th>
                      
                          </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                           <th><input type="text" name="LOTE" id="LOTE"></input> 
                             <th><input type="text" name="CADUCIDAD" id="CADUCIDAD"></th>
                             <th><input type="text" name="EXISTENCIA" id="EXISTENCIA"></th>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                            <th><input type="text" name="LOTE" id="LOTE"></th>
                            <th><input type="text" name="CADUCIDAD" id="CADUCIDAD"></th>
                            <th><input type="text" name="EXISTENCIA" id="EXISTENCIA"></th>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th><input type="text" name="LOTE" id="LOTE"></th>
                            <th><input type="text" name="CADUCIDAD" id="CADUCIDAD"></th>
                            <th><input type="text" name="EXISTENCIA" id="EXISTENCIA"></th>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>

                      </table>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                  </form>

                </div>
              </div>   
            </div>
          </div> 
        </div>      
        <br>
        <!--SCRIPT-->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
      </html>

      <!------->
      <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/main.js"></script>
      <!------->
    </body>
    </html>


Debes aprender a debugear lo que haces. Una línea antes del echo json_encode($return_arr); escribe esto: file_put_contents('debug_array.txt', print_r($return_arr, true)); y ejecútalo una vez, luego te vas a la carpeta donde esté el archivo que estás ejecutando y mira si te ha creado el archivo debug_array.txt y examinas su contenido, a ver si aparece todo tal como pretendes, y si es así aprende a tratarlo después. Y sino entonces revisa tu código antes de eso hasta que aparezca como tu quieres.

Hola, @masterguru. Gracias por tu guía, ya agregué la línea de código que me escribiste, corrí mi código y sí me aparece el archivo debug_array.txt. Voy a revisar para adecuarlo a mi código, gracias.

Por lo que entiendo quieres que tu JSON en lugar de devolverte esto:
{
  "": {
    "value": "22",
    "CLAVE": "22",
    "DESCRIPCION": "Caseinato de calcio en Polvo. Cada 100 g contienen: Proteínas 86.0 g a 90.0 g. Grasas 0.0 a 2.0 g. Minerales 3.8 a 6.0 g. Humedad 0.0 a 6.2 g.",
    "UM": "Envase con 100 g.",
    "ID": "3",
    "LOTE": [
      "403402041B",
      "A304003",
      "E404019"
    ],
    "CADUCIDAD": [
      "31-ago-25",
      "30-abr-25",
      "31-ene-26"
    ],
    "EXISTENCIA": [
      "4030",
      "1792",
      "1792"
    ]
  }
}

te devuelva esto:
[
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "CLAVE": "22",
    "DESCRIPCION": "Caseinato de calcio en Polvo. Cada 100 g contienen: Proteínas 86.0 g a 90.0 g. Grasas 0.0 a 2.0 g. Minerales 3.8 a 6.0 g. Humedad 0.0 a 6.2 g.",
    "UM": "Envase con 100 g.",
    "LOTE": "403402041B",
    "CADUCIDAD": "31-ago-25",
    "EXISTENCIA": "4030"
  },
  {
    "ID": "2",
    "CLAVE": "22",
    "DESCRIPCION": "Caseinato de calcio en Polvo. Cada 100 g contienen: Proteínas 86.0 g a 90.0 g. Grasas 0.0 a 2.0 g. Minerales 3.8 a 6.0 g. Humedad 0.0 a 6.2 g.",
    "UM": "Envase con 100 g.",
    "LOTE": "A304003",
    "CADUCIDAD": "30-abr-25",
    "EXISTENCIA": "1792"
  },
  {
    "ID": "3",
    "CLAVE": "22",
    "DESCRIPCION": "Caseinato de calcio en Polvo. Cada 100 g contienen: Proteínas 86.0 g a 90.0 g. Grasas 0.0 a 2.0 g. Minerales 3.8 a 6.0 g. Humedad 0.0 a 6.2 g.",
    "UM": "Envase con 100 g.",
    "LOTE": "E404019",
    "CADUCIDAD": "31-ene-26",
    "EXISTENCIA": "1792"
  }
]

Para eso utiliza $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) en lugar de mysqli_fetch_array en tu función runQuery, y ya te devolverá los registros en un array con todas sus claves. No necesitas el foreach final, devuelves los datos directamente echo json_encode($faq).
